# How can I force this CSS grid to wrap to a new line without specifying minmax sizes?

Tags: css, css-grid, word-wrap

I come from a heavy div/float background to build responsive sites (e.g. Bootstrap 3, Foundation) and used Flex box briefly but have been attempting to use Grid everywhere since it's been really great at solving a number of problems. I seem to run into "simple" problems like this all too often and feel like I'm missing some basics, and can't find the answer in docs. Anyways, to the code.

Given a grid setup like so:

```
display: grid;
grid-auto-columns: max-content;
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

the content doesn't wrap to a new row once it's filled the width of its parent element. Ideally, I'd be able to have it auto-wrap without pre-defining exact pixel measurements such as `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));`. This doesn't seem to work for my needs – I'd have to define multiple `grid-template-columns` measurements for different viewports, and know what a good width is for the items inside the columns. I'd much rather say `grid-auto-columns: max-content;` and then have items simply wrap to a new line.

Is this possible with grid? What am I missing/misunderstanding?

See Codepen with a full example demonstrating the problem: https://codepen.io/csdv/pen/OrbrzJ

Comment: I think this might help you, I had a similar question, since I wanted to have a minimum number of columns but be able to wrap them even if there was space remaining https://stackoverflow.com/q/53434024/8437694

Comment: AFAIK you always have to be specific with grid-items width in some way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't see how this is possible with the [current iteration of CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/).

As you've already discovered, you would at least need to define a fixed minimum width on the columns, in order to force a wrap at some point.

Unfortunately, with automatic repetitions, the minimum length cannot be `auto`, `min-content` or `max-content` alone, because that is [forbidden in the specification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52504049/3597276).

Here's as close as you can get with Grid, as far as I can tell:

```css
.btn-tabs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, max-content));
  width: 20rem;
}

/* original demo styles */
.btn {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #77aaee;
  color: #77aaee;
  padding: .6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-tabs">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 3</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 4</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 5</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 6</a>
</div>
```

Flexbox may be a good alternative, as it seems to work with your requirements:

```css
.btn-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 20rem;
}

/* original demo styles */
/* notice no width defined on flex items, but they wrap anyway */
.btn {
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #77aaee;
  color: #77aaee;
  padding: .6rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-tabs">
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 1</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 2</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 3</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 4</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 5</a>
  <a class="btn" href="#">Button 6</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. I can get behind the idea of forcing a minimum width and letting the rest auto calculate. I've settled on this which does what I'm looking for – thanks Michael! `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10rem, auto));`

Comment: Looks good. Yeah, `auto` is even better because it does what you want and makes the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Spec the grid dim in %, like:

```
grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
```

or

```
grid-template-columns: 25% auto auto auto;
```

The text will auto wrap inside the grid element defined as a %...