# CSS Grid overflowing

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying for a couple of hours to make this work, but I still failed.
I need to put labels in the grid, but maximally 3 columns. If it doesn't fit, then wrap it to the next row. If it is possible items can reorder to fit as many as possible to row.

I made a code snippet here:

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 280px;
}

label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: grid; */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 30%));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bafang M500</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bafang MaxDrive</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Active Plus</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Performance</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Performance CX</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>OLI SPORT</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Shimano StePS E6000</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Shimano STePS E6100</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Yamaha PW-ST</label>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>500<</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>500</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>400</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>300</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>200</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>100</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/><100</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: why not `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif i need variable columns count, if it fit then 3, if it doesn't fit then 2 or 1

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290215/8620333 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif  i tried to use `repeat(auto-fill,minmax(max(0,100%/4),1fr));` but then all labels are on top of each other and when i use `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(100% / 3 - 20px), 1fr));` thenall of items are forced into 3 columns and text is overflowing over another text

Comment: `repeat(auto-fill,minmax(max(0px,100%/4),1fr))` <-- you need px to 0

Comment: @TemaniAfif i used that and text is still overflowing https://pasteboard.co/JHjMhxq.png

Answer (score 1):

just the minmax, it works on different size.

```
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [@gregory-broyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13607613/gregory-broyer) answer is appliable for the upper wrapper, but not fully for the lower. But I define a 2nd class for 2n wrapper, and set `grid-template-columns` to the original.

The demo is available here:

```css
body {
  background-color: #555;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 280px;
}

label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  display: grid; */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  //grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 30%));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
}
.wrapper-h{
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(max-content, 30%));
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bafang M500</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bafang MaxDrive</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Active Plus</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Performance</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Bosch Performance CX</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>OLI SPORT</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Shimano StePS E6000</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Shimano STePS E6100</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>Yamaha PW-ST</label>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper wrapper-h">
    <label><input type="checkbox"/>500<</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>500</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>400</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>300</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>200</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>100</label>
      <label><input type="checkbox"/>&lt100</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so there isn't som way to make it into only one class?

Comment: Increase width of main-wrapper, or use shorter strings in 1st wrapper

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the answer it self, not off site.