# How do I limit the number of divs in a flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a div set to flex and row wrap. Inside I have a collection of divs each containing a picture. As the width of the viewport increases, they re-arrange themselves correctly, but I would like to limit the number of pictures per row. I can get this done by changing the width of the pictures but that gets tiresome. Is there a simpler way, something like a "max-boxes-per-row" concept? Below is the relevant CSS

```
#gallery-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80vw;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;

  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290215/8620333

Comment: Well, let's say there is a solution. How will you deal with adaptability?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#gallery-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3); /* Adjust the 3 in calc(100% / 3) to your preferred maximum number of pictures per row. */
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;

  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Great solution, but it creates one issue. As the screen gets larger the images become too large and if I add a max-width then is starts putting 4 or 5 or 6 images in a row once they can fit. It's not the end of the world. For the moment I changed it to 80wv/3 as opposed to 100vw, so it buys me a little more room. - Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `display:grid` so you can specify how many `span` in 1 row. You can learn more about this [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)