# Is there a way to set the maximum grid columns allowed in minmax()?

Tags: css

I'm using this `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));` for my gallery page and it's working great when I scale down my page, but I don't want to have more than 5 images in a row when I scale it up. I can use this `grid-template-columns:repeat(5, 1fr);` with `@media` and specify the width to have 4 images then 3 ... but I'm just checking if I can do it with the first one. thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907270/how-to-specify-the-maximum-number-of-columns-repeat-will-create-using-auto-fit

Comment: yes it does, thanks a lot